# Dynamic searching on azure table

Tags: algorithm, search, azure, azure-table-storage

Anyone knows or had experience on designing azure table to fit for dynamic searching?
I have a Library class:

```
public class LibraryDocument
{
    public string DocumentNumber { get; set; }
    public string Complaint { get; set; }
    public string Respondent { get; set; }
    public string DocumentDate { get; set; }
    public string Division { get; set; }
    public string DocumentType { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Footer { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string[] FooterItems { get; set; }
    public string[] RespondentList { get; set; }
    public string[] ComplaintList { get; set; }
}
```

I need to convert this to an azure table.

`Input:` Client will send a keyword through api
`Process:` The system must be able to match the keyword in all library data
`Output:` Return Partitionkeys and Rowkeys of matched data

I can't think of a better way to design the tables needed.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Azure Storage Tables are not designed to support such usage, mainly because rows' only indices are the combination of their PartitionKey + RowKey, so any query that does not rely on the PK (at least) and the RK is highly inefficient (the server will basically parse all rows!).

I would suggest having a look at Lucene.NET, which is a search engine that can be deployed on Azure. Some resources:

- [Solr/Lucene on Azure](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/Windows-Azure-Solr)
- [Search on Azure :: Using Lucene.NET](http://codingfields.com/guides/search-on-azure-using-lucene-net/%20%22Search%20on%20Azure%20%3a%3a%20Using%20Lucene.NET)
- [Solr Installer for Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/common-tasks/solr-installer-for-windows-azure/)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that table storage in general is a great solution for dynamic searching.  I would advice that you consider using Lucene.NET with the Azure Directory https://azuredirectory.codeplex.com/ or some other search engine to implement this logic.

However, if you must have ATS provide the search capabilities, consider creating two tables:
LibraryDocuments table would contain all of the LibraryDocument objects.  PartitionKey/RowKey combos would be unique and provide business meaning/key information to each document.
Create a LibraryIndex table that would partitionKey off each possible keyword and RowKey of a LibraryDocument's PartitionKey/RowKey conctatinated combination, where that keyword could be found. IE: the Index table would provide an index to LibraryDocuments

This way your searches would always be PartitionKey attuned and thus faster.  However, this search might still do multiple requests as partitionkey matches can span multiple storage transactions and require continuation tokens (etags)
Also, you'll have trouble doing "contains" types of searches and generally taking this system anywhere further then basic keyword search or at best a "starts-with" search.

HTH